# Javascript replace text function

Tags: javascript, replace

This is my javascript for replacing some text:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Sometext/g, 'difference');
```

Ho do I change color, font-size, font and such?

I need to link my script like this, can't use { otherwise:

```
<script>$(document).ready($.getScript("url"));</script>
```

I though something like this would work:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.body.innerHTML =
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Deckling/g, result);
}

var str = "The Liberator";
var result =     str.fontcolor("Red").italics().fontsize(6);
result.style.fontFamily = "Harrington";
```

Any help? (first post and very limited Knowledge)

Comment: Can you please make yourself a bit more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you text in a `div` or `span` tag, select it in JS applying a class.

The class will contains the style for your text.

Just a quick example in vanilla javaScript (no jquery):
http://jsbin.com/yufiteseme/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .a {
    color:red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 6px;
    {
    </style>
     <script>
    function changeColor(){
        document.getElementById('text').classList.add('a');
    } 
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="changeColor()">
     <div id="text">
    Test for example
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps I need to evaluate a bit better. What I need to do is replacing all instances of one word with another that also changes the properties of that word. This is done one a forum so html the sign { or } will not work directly. I can link the css style like this:    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url">
    </head> So I could add that and:`function changeColor(){
        document.getElementById('text').classList.add('a');
    }` to my first line of code and it would work?

Comment: I suppose yes, but the best would be to look at your code. Could you pllease create a http://jsfiddle.net/ simulating your problem? So we can fix it live, and give you a proper solution. Thanks!

Comment: Solved it, it was so easy I overlooked it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can change style of an html element using javascript, put your script below the element.

The following example changes the style of a 'p' element using javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("p1").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("p1").style.fontFamily = "Arial";
        document.getElementById("p1").style.fontSize = "larger";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also change style of an html element using jquery.

The following example changes the style of a 'p' element using jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#p1').ready(function(){
            $('#p1').css({"color": "green"}).css({"fontFamily": "Arial"}).css({"fontSize": "24px"});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

That will not work:
`var result =     str.fontcolor("Red").italics().fontsize(6);`.
You need to add css to change the surface.Add this to your header:

```
  .textstyle{
     font-size:16px;
     font-family:Harrington;
  }
</style>
```

And add this to your window.onload:`$('body').addClass('textstyle');`